# Count MongoDB collection row

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to know how i can get a count of all the rows i get out of my MongoDB collection.

```
var collection = db.collection( _collection ).find();
```

Right now i don't know about there are somting or not in it, if need to follow on how maney rows i get out from my collection.

are there somene better way for me to get my "data" out widtout using the Stream function?

```
var stream = collection.find().stream();            
stream.on("data", function(item)
{
    console.log(item.zipcode);
});

stream.on("end", function()
{
});
```

how i can get a kind of help, :)

Comment: `db.collection().find().count()`?

Comment: i have trying, but width out luck... i think maby i do somthing worng :)

Comment: Where are you doing this?

Comment: i'm trying to build a Node.JS webservices handler when i are using MongoDB to handle my data, but the problem is i can find out of how i can count my rows out widt out to get a bug :/

Comment: Hvae you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318086/mongodb-count-collection-node-js ?

Comment: What library are you using to interact with MongoDB? Is it mongodb or mongoose? Or some other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used the Node.JS driver at all, but looking at the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#count), it appears that `Collection()` has a count function on it:

```
// Assuming DB has an open connection...
db.collection("my_collection", function(err, collection) {
    collection.count(function(err, count)) {
        // Assuming no errors, 'count' should have your answer
    }
});
```

Does that help at all?

As for the second part of your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but here are a couple of ways of getting your data:

Using the `toArray()` function to give you an array of all documents ([see docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find)):

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    // 'docs' should contain an array of all your documents
    // 'docs.length' will give you the length of the array (how many docs)
});
```

Using the `each()` function to loop over the results and execute the given function for each one ([see docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each)):

```
collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {
    // this function will be executed once per document

    console.log(doc.zipcode)
});
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: This only works if he is using the node-mongodb-native driver. If he is using a wrapper such as Mongoose, he needs to access the underlying driver to use `toArray` and `each`

Comment: This is true. I made the assumption he was, based on the fact he refers to the stream function (which the native driver has), and the lack of any further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the "find().each(...) function its what there resolved med problem ^^