# MongoDB get the number of documents (count) in a collection using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm currently writing a function that should return the number of documents from a collection the thing is that when i'm returning the value it says undefined, Here is my code:

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


// open the connection the DB server
var dbName = "ystocks";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";
var tt = "mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
//"mongodb://localhost:27017/ystocks"
function getNumOfDocs (collectionName, host, port, dbName) {
    var tt = "mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
    count = 0;
    MongoClient.connect(tt, function (error, db){

        if(error) throw error;
        collectionName = collectionName;
        db.collection(collectionName).count({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
            if (error) throw error;

            //print the result
            console.dir("numOfDocs: " + numOfDocs);
            count = numOfDocs;
            console.log("count is : " + count);

            // close the DB
            return numOfDocs;
            db.close();


        });// end of count

    }); // Connection to the DB
    //return count;

} // end of getNumOfDocs


var ee = getNumOfDocs ("stocks", "localhost", "27017", "ystocks");
console.log("ee is " + ee);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you tell us what exact message/error you are getting?

Comment: It's an error but my variable should get the number of docs instead it says in the console : 'ee is undefined'

Comment: You can't return the result of asynchronous function calls, you have to use a callback.

Comment: Can you show me some example I'll need to use this value in order to run a for loop

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call. It's the same issue as Ajax calls in jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how it *should* look like

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "ystocks";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";

function getNumOfDocs (collectionName, host, port, dbName, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, function (error, db){
        if(error) return callback(error);

        db.collection(collectionName).count({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
            if(error) return callback(error);

            db.close();
            callback(null, numOfDocs);
        });
    }); 
}
```

And usage

```
getNumOfDocs("stocks", host, port, dbName, function(err, count) {
   if (err) {
       return console.log(err.message);
   }
   console.log('number of documents', count);
});
```

Keep in mind if you are going to call this function lots of times,  it is better to just connect to the database once and then use the same connection.

Comment: I've done this and in the usage i've added this :
var a = getNumOfDocs("stocks", host, port, dbName, function(err, count) {
   if (err) {
       return console.log(err.message);
   }
   console.log('number of documents', count);
   return count;
});

console.log("a is :" + a);
I'm still getting a is undefined

Comment: That is normal. The return value of getNumOfDocs is undefined, the calls inside are async, meaning they don't complete immediately but at a later point in time so there is no way to return a value like you do.

Answer (score 3):

The use of **count()** is deprecated since mongodb 4.0.

Instead you should use **documentCount()** alternative, but is much moere slower than **count()** with large ammounts of data.

The alternatives are **estimatedDocumentCount()** that performs quite well and the usage is:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "ystocks";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";

function getNumOfDocs (collectionName, host, port, dbName, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, function (error, db){
        if(error) return callback(error);

        db.collection(collectionName).estimatedDocumentCount({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
            if(error) return callback(error);

            db.close();
            callback(null, numOfDocs);
        });
    }); 
}
```

Another option I use is to get the number of documents from the **collection stats**:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "ystocks";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";

function getNumOfDocs (collectionName, host, port, dbName, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, function (error, db){
        if(error) return callback(error);

        db.collection(collectionName).stats(function(error, stats){
            if(error) return callback(error);

            db.close();
            callback(null, stats.count);
        });
    }); 
}
```