# How can I return the number of documents in a MongoDB collection using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count

I need to write a function that return the number of documents in a collection using Node.js. This is my code (I've followed the advice found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473650/mongodb-get-the-number-of-documents-count-in-a-collection-using-node-js)):

```
async function countCollections(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) callback(error);
    var dbo = db.db(nameDB);
    dbo.collection(nameCollections).find(query).count(function(err, count) {
      if (err) callback(error);
      db.close();
      callback(null, count);
    });
  });
}
```

I call this function in this way:

```
await countCollections(function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Number of documents: ', count);
});
```

Using this method, I can just view the count value, but I can't directly use. How can I do to obtain into a variable the count value when I call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mongo's [countDocuments] method.(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/).

```
let count = await db.collection(nameCollections).countDocuments(query)
```

Also without really knowing how your app works i recommend you don't open a new Mongo connection every time the function calls but to open it once when your app starts.

Comment: Thank you, but it would seem not to work. Could you be more precise?
And how can I connect to Mongo just one time?

Comment: Again i'm unsure how your app looks but in theory you connect to mongo when you start your app then you either pass the connection as a parameter between functions or better yet have a "helper" class that holds the client and can give it to anyone who asks.